# How to improve Surface Pro 4 resolution when running Linux Mint Mate in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, resolution, microsoft-surface

The screen is too small and I can't seem to work out how to fix it.
Can anyone experimenting with or knowing about Linux Mint in a Surface Pro 4 help?